Website alternating between old and new versions despite DNS happening over 48 hours ago
We have recently released a new version of our website and well over 50 hours ago we changed the DNS for the domain. Traffic is going to the new website now, however, randomly it will still send our users (and us, we see it a lot, roughly 50% of the time) to the legacy website as well.
Everything is hosted in AWS. Our legacy website uses CloudFront distribution to redirect requests through to an API Gateway. Our new setup sends users to a Global Accelerator that sends the user onto an ALB. We use CloudFlare as our DNS provider and everything in there points to the new IP addresses from Accelerator. We've checked the propagation worldwide, and everything is pointing to the IP addresses we're expecting them to point to (and has done for days), yet randomly we still get pointed to the old CloudFront Distribution with the API Gateway.
My question is: what would cause requests to be delivered to either an AWS Global Accelerator or a CloudFront distribution on a random basis, despite all a-records being pointed to the Accelerator? Where is this request getting lost? How can I see the pathway of the request and where it's getting diverted?
I'm happy to share the domain if required, or provide any more information. Additionally, I understand if this question isn't specific enough, vote to close in that instance but we're at a loss here - I've not seen this behaviour before.
EDIT:
Attached a pic of us pinging the same URL seconds apart, and getting different responses.

EDIT:
Is it possibly these NS records causing a fuss?


We've checked the propagation worldwide, and everything is pointing to the IP addresses we're expecting them to point to show us. Using: https://dnschecker.org

DNS doesn't propagate, it's a distributed cache. It could be that the TTL used to be very high, but CloudFlare usually uses low TTLs, so it's probably not that. Have you updated all records, A, CNAME, etc?

Did you previously use CloudFlare as the DNS provider, or was it CloudFront as well? i.e. what NS records did you previously have at your registrar (GoDaddy) specifically?
